# Are there any Stack Exchange website(s) for asking questions about animals and birds?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

what i want to ask

I decided to launch a donation website and app.
Here is the concept of not get more then one rupees, and here want to collect one rs (indian currency) for the animals and birds that required water in the summer of Rajasthan. Here my motive is not to collect the money here I just want to spread awareness regarding the needy of that awareness the animals can not say own problem but have understand. Here with one rupees I am getting their presence with me in this subject.

What you would suggest me?

Comment: An appeal for donations isn’t really a question that fits the Q&A format of any Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @Xufox Thanks for commenting here i am using donation word to clear my question its not actually that means.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be advertising for donations and/or for spreading awareness.

Comment: @PolyGeo please suggest where i can ask my this question recommend a site.then you free to close this

Comment: It does not look suitable for any Stack Exchange site because it appears to have an advertising purpose.

Comment: _"then you free to close this".._ Since this is on the borderline to being not just blatantly off topic but can also considered as being spam, I don't think we need your permission/consent to close this question ;)

Comment: i update my query as per community guideline only requesting site recommendation so remove hold please i want help regarding this.

Comment: Please don't edit your question in such a way that it invalidates existing answers. (FWIW, I'm not sure if it should be closed - maybe the users who did will be satisfied if you anonymize your question by removing the geographical information?)

Comment: on this post you all wrong i think,according to the [site- recommendation] tag. please see this tags description accuratly.according to tag i  just ask for the site recommendations and also give detail of questions this is not spam at all.

Answer (score 8):

To answer the question in your title:

> Are there any Stack Exchange website(s) for asking questions about animals and birds?

Yes, we have sites about [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com) and [Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com). @CharlieBrumbaugh mentions [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/), and we even have questions about [The Birds](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-birds) on Movies & TV. (Just joking about the last one; it's Friday...)

As for what you're asking in the *body*, I have no idea. If you have a programming question about the website and apps you're building, it might fit on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). If you have a question about hosting or SEO, it could be on-topic for [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). If you have a *specific* question about how to manage the community you're creating (so not just "how do I get more participants"), [we even have a site for that](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/).

If you want an accepted way to raise money (or even increase awareness) on Stack Exchange, I'd suggest to leave a short summary and a link to the website in your profile. Answer/ask a lot of good questions, which increases the chance that users might visit your profile and if they're especially thankful for your post, they *might* donate something to a good cause.

Comment: Thanks i will share a link inside profile thats a much good idea.i can more explain my idea if you allow for discussion here.

Comment: There is also Outdoors.se https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birds

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately - I don't think there's a *great* fit for that sort of question *precisely* because its not a question.

You've *built* a thing. The moment you figure you want to use SE sites proper to *raise awareness* - you're *advertising*. Even with good intentions, you risk being seen as [a spammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).Putting it in your profile is fine, assuming the right people see it.

While there's a precedent for community selected open source ads "selling" that idea to a community would be interesting, and most communities I can think of where you *could* pitch it don't have ads right now. It would probably want/need a meta post first. Pets would have a good crossover of interest, but not topics. Great outdoors *might* work. This would of course need SO convinced that running community ads for charitable projects is a good idea, and proving said bona fides for the projects

*Essentially*, there's no good site to do what you want to do.

(Incidentally, when folks offer to tip me for answers, I tell them to donate to a local dog charity - so you could do some good simply by being awesome - not a grand way to do some good, but hopefully I got some shelter mutt a meal or two).

Comment: thanks i update my query please suggest now

Comment: Glorfindel's answer covers what I'd talk about. That said, editing a post *that* substantially - and invalidating current answers isn't really fair to folks who answered.